# SOBRE MYSQL E FOREIGN KEY

Tags: mysql

Boa noite galera! Tenho um database com as tabelas:

- PASSAGEIROS
- MOTORISTAS
- VIAGENS

---

- Para cada viagem é designado um motorista.
- Mais de um passageiro pode ir na mesma viagem.

Dúvida: Como eu faço para referenciar mais de um passageiro em uma mesma viagem por FK?

Comment: Supondo que o passageiro não seja indexado pelo CPF e seja 'descartável', ou seja, cada linha de passageiro seja criada para uma só viagem, é o passageiro quem referencia a viagem como chave estrangeira.

Comment: é só criar uma tabela de n para n por exemplo passageiros_viagens, onde nessa tabela você vai armazenar id_passageiro e id_viagem.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma tabela de muitos para muitos, e referenciar a viagem e os passageiros, vou postar um exemplo.
Obs: não criei a tabela com `pk's` nem `fk's`, pois é apenas para você entender a modelagem e as `query's`.

```
CREATE TABLE passageiros(
    id INT, 
    nome VARCHAR(50)
);
INSERT INTO passageiros VALUES
(1,'Passageiro 1'),(2,'Passageiro 2'),(3,'Passageiro 3'),(4,'Passageiro 4'),(5,'Passageiro 5');

CREATE TABLE motoristas(id INT, nome VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO motoristas VALUES
(1,'Motorista 1'),(2,'Motorista 2'),(3,'Motorista 3');

CREATE TABLE viagens(id INT, id_motorista INT, descricao VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO viagens VALUES
(1,2,'Viagem 1'), (2,3,'Viagem 2');

CREATE TABLE passageiros_viagens(id INT, id_passageiro INT, id_viagem INT);

INSERT INTO passageiros_viagens VALUES
(1,1,1),(2,3,1),(3,5,1),(4,2,2),(5,5,2);
```

Caso eu queira saber os passageiros que estão na viagem 1, executo a seguinte query:

```
 SELECT
        p.*
    FROM viagens v
    INNER JOIN motoristas m
    ON m.id = v.id_motorista
    INNER JOIN passageiros_viagens pv
    ON pv.id_viagem = v.id
    INNER JOIN passageiros p
    ON p.id = pv.id_passageiro
    WHERE v.id = 1;
```

Ou posso usar dessa maneira usando o `GROUP_CONCAT` e trazer em apenas uma linha para melhor visualização:

```
  SELECT
        v.descricao,
        m.nome,
        GROUP_CONCAT(p.nome SEPARATOR ', ') AS passageiros
    FROM viagens v
    INNER JOIN motoristas m
    ON m.id = v.id_motorista
    INNER JOIN passageiros_viagens pv
    ON pv.id_viagem = v.id
    INNER JOIN passageiros p
    ON p.id = pv.id_passageiro
    WHERE v.id = 1;
```